# Is there an alternate resource similar to Mozscape by SEOmoz?

Tags: seo, links, seo-audit

I was wondering if there is an alternate (free or paid) resource similar to SEOmoz's [Linkscape (now Mozscape)](http://www.seomoz.org/api) where the entire web is indexed and a website's entire link profile is scraped and documented.

Answer (score 1):

[Ahrefs](http://ahrefs.com/) updates pretty frequently. They have limited free accounts and some tiered paid options.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think SEOmoz (or even Google) has indexed the whole web! The ones I use are:

- [Open Site Explorer](http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/): now part of SEOmoz's offering
- [Majestic SEO](http://www.majesticseo.com): don't forget to register
- [SEOprofiler](http://www.sepprofiler.com): my favourite paid tool